# Evaluating Infinite Series with Binomial Coefficient

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, binomial-coefficients

**I am not sure whether my argument works. I think I'm mostly concerned with how I'm working with the binomial coefficient. So I am wondering if I can get feed back as to whether my argument is correct/ the series is divergent or not.**

> Evaluate the following series:
> $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} {3k \choose k} \cdot 7!$$

Let us begin by considering the sequence of partial sums:
$$ S_k = {3k \choose k} \cdot 7!$$
for $ k \in \mathbb{N}: k >1$. This expression can be expanded and rewritten to give:
$$  S_k = {3k \choose k} \cdot 7! = \left( \frac {(3k)!}{k!  \cdot (2k)!} \right) \cdot 7! = \left( \frac{(3k) \cdot (3k - 1) \cdot ... \cdot (2k + 1)}{k!} \right) \cdot 7! $$
Now, in order to evaluate the convergence, or lack thereof, of the infinite series we will consider the limit of the ratio $ \frac {S_{k + 1}}{S_k}$. In order to do this, we must first find an expression for $S_{k + 1}$:
$$S_{k+1} = {3(k+1) \choose k+1} \cdot 7! = \left( \frac {(3k + 3)!}{(k + 1)! \cdot (2 k + 2)!} \right) \cdot 7! = \left( \frac{(3k + 3) \cdot (3k + 2) \cdot ... \cdot (2k + 3)}{(k + 1)!} \right) \cdot 7!$$
Finally, denote the aforementioned limit of the ratio $ \frac {S_{k + 1}}{S_k}$ by $Q$ and observe that:
$$Q = \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{S_{k + 1}}{S_k} = \lim_{k\to\infty} \left( \frac{3k + 3) \cdot (3k + 2) \cdot ... \cdot (2k + 3)}{(k + 1)!} \cdot \frac{k!}{(3k) \cdot (3k - 1) \cdot ... \cdot (2k + 1)} \right)$$
$$ =  \lim_{k\to\infty} \left( \frac {(3k + 3) \cdot (3k + 2) \cdot (3k + 1)}{(k + 1) \cdot (2k + 2) \cdot (2k + 1)} \right) = \frac {27}{4}$$
We have found $Q = \frac{27}{4}$ and thus, clearly, have that $Q > 1$. It follows from the Quotient test for absolute convergence that the series $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} {3k \choose k} \cdot 7!$ is divergent, or:
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} {3k \choose k} \cdot 7! = \infty$$

Comment: Since $\binom {3k}{k} \ge 1$, there is no question that the series is divergent.

Comment: Quite.  By the simplest of series tests, you must have that the summands in an infinite series must approach zero if you have any hope of the limit being finite.  If the summands do not approach zero then you can be sure that the sum will diverge.  Also, it is improper to write that the sum "equals infinity", it is better to say it with words that it "diverges to infinity."  (*N.b. the summands approaching zero is a necessary but not a sufficient condition on the series converging.  See for example the harmonic series*)

Comment: $\displaystyle{3k \choose k} \propto {\left(27/4\right)^{k} \over \sqrt{k}}$ as $\displaystyle k \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This argument works, but here are the ways to make it simpler:

- you can immediately drop $7!$ as constant factors have no bearing on convergence
- argument itself: so the series cannot converge, you can argue either that

  - $\binom{3k}{k} > 1$ or
  - $\binom{3k+3}{k+1} > \binom{3k}{k}$